# If the derivative of $f$ is never zero, then $f$ is one-to-one

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

This is an exercise from Abbott's second edition of Understanding Analysis.

> Let $f$ be differentiable on an interval $A$. Show that if $f'(x) \neq 0$ on $A$, show that $f$ is one-to-one on $A$. Provide an example to show that the converse statement need not be true.

Is my solution (below) correct?

Let $x_{1},x_{2} \in A $ such that $x_1 \neq x_2$. Since the function satisfies all the conditions of the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in (x_1,x_2)$ [without loss of generality we consider $x_1 < x_2$] such that $f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2 -x_1) f'(c) \neq 0$ as it is given that $f'(x)$ is nonzero on $A$ and $x_1 \neq x_2$ is our assumption. Therefore $x_1 \neq x_2$ implies $f(x_1) \neq  f(x_2)$ for every $x_1,x_2 \in A$. Thus $f$ is one-to one on $A$.

The converse may not be true. Consider $A=[-1,1)$ and $f(x)= x^3$. Therefore $f$ is injective on $A$. Again $f'(x)= 2x^2$. Therefore $f'(0)=0, 0 \in A$. So the converse need not be true.

Comment: That all looks good.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Furthermore, you can also prove that $f$ is monotone.

Comment: Excellent, especially for "self" study.  For problems at this level whenever you see the phrase "differentiable on an interval"  the natural response is "mean-value theorem perhaps."  Later on you will get many more techniques and the MVT will look kind of quaint.  But, for now, it should be similar to someone asking "How to get this nail in?" and the response "Try a hammer."

Comment: This isn't contributing much to the conversation but I just thought I'd let you know this is a really nice proof and may have made me dislike analysis a little less

Comment: Wow that's really nice and compact!!!

Answer (score 6):

If the function is differentiable and $f'(x)\neq0$, by the [Darboux Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_%28analysis%29) it has the intermediate value property.

Suppose by contradiction that there are two real numbers $x_1,x_2 \in A$ such that $f'(x_1)<0$ and $f'(x_2)>0$. This implies the existence of $x_3\in A$ s.t. $f'(x_3)=0$, contradicting the hypothesis $f'(x)\neq 0$.

Because the derivative $f'$ is either strictly positive or strictly negative on $A$, $f$ is monotonic and hence injective.

Comment: Yes. It might be worth remembering, however, that one proves Darboux's theorem by appealing to the mean-value theorem in much the same way that the OP did.  So this is not really a different method, just a different way of expressing the same proof via a detour to Darboux.  Even so it is good to remind students about this property, so that they are not always reduced to an appeal to the MVT.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I do not know this proof. The proof I know of the Darboux theorem relies on showing (through Weierstrass) that the auxiliary function $\varphi(t)=f(t)-tx$ has a maximum on $(a,b)$.

Comment: I see that this proof you learned is preferred by Wiki, so likely nowadays the best known.  Notice, too, that the OP proof could have been written in much the same way by an appeal to Rolle's theorem.  After a while all these proofs and problems look the same since they all in the end are just simple arguments about continuous functions $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ that are differentiable on $(a,b)$.