# If $f'(x)$ is nonzero for every $x \in\mathbb R$, then $f(1)$ is different from $f(0)$, true or false?

Tags: functions, derivatives

> If $f'(x)$ is nonzero for every $x \in\mathbb R$, then $f(1)$ is different from $f(0)$, true or false?

Technically I would say its true, if given the fact the function was continuous, but the question is really vague on that aspect, what do you guys say?

If $f'(x)$ is never zero, it means it does never change the signal of the slope of $f(x)$, which means that $f(1)$ would never be equal to $f(0)$, but is that enough of a proof to consider it true?

Comment: if f'(x) is in R for every x, f is continuous at every x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the derivative of $f$ is never zero, then $f$ is one-to-one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532358/if-the-derivative-of-f-is-never-zero-then-f-is-one-to-one). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3166315/42969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Technically I would say its true, if given the fact the function was continuous

Note that you require $f'(x)$ to exist at every $x$. And a function differentiable at $x$ is continuous at $x$, i.e. your $f$ is automatically continuous.

Then the classical [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) states:

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)$ then there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

So this is a straight forward application of this theorem.

Comment: but the thing is that the question doesn't tell you that f is continuous, can I just assume that and use the theorem?

Comment: @TottyAmadeus A differentiable function is automatically continuous. Your problem assumes that $f'(x)$ exists for all real $x$, so your $f$ is continuous on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Also note that the assumption about $f$ being continuous (in the Rolle's theorem) is only a slight generalization to the case where $f$ is differentiable everywhere except for the ends of the $[a,b]$ interval. However it is required to be continuous there. But you consider a function differentiable on whole $\mathbb{R}$ so it isn't really relevant. I've updated the answer.

Comment: yep, you're right, that cleared it to me
thank you !

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle f(1)-f(0)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=f'(c)$ for some $c\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Note that this uses [the mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) which on the other hand is proved using the Rolle's theorem.

Comment: A duplicate IMO, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3166315/42969.